# Need endswith dot and one number

Tags: java, android, ends-with

I need the conditional if my number inserted in an EditText ends with dot+any number.
Example:

129.2

if ends with this, need that the new value like this.

192.20

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using a `NumberFormat` for the output?

```
double a = 123.2;       
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String aFormat = formatter.format(a);
System.out.println(aFormat); // --> 123.20
```

So you can easyly change you preferend output format.
More info: [NumberFormat - Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a conditional, you can work with regular expressions:

```
if (yourString.matches(".*\\.\\d")) {
    ...
}
```

The regular expressions above matches any String that ends with a dot and single digit. For more information on regular expressions see e.g. the Pattern documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html